# SelectedLabel spark ComboBox

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

this function bellow returns the String for display in an item renderer.

```
public function itemToLabel(item:Object):String
```

As `selectedLabel` property is obsolete in `spark.components.ComboBox` i added this function :

```
public function get selectedLabel():String 
    {
        var item:Object = selectedItem;
        return itemToLabel(item);
    }
```

But i am blocked about the `public function set selectedLabel(label:String):void`

is there anyone who know a function `labelToItem` or another solution to set my combobox `selectedLabel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most performant solution, but if you don't have a ton of items in the **dataprovider** then this should be alright:

```
public function setSelectedLabel(cb:ComboBox, label:String):void
{
    for each(var item:Object in cb.dataProvider)
    {
        if(item[cb.labelField] == label)
        {
            cb.selectedItem = item;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you i think that it seems as i need but you missed the return value of the actionScript i added it (void)